# Unable to show user specific link to specific page in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I would like to create user specific links. I mean, when user signed up and logged in, he has redirected to **create/** page. In that page user fills out the form and after pressing button, user has to redirect to **list/** page, where there are user specific links to specific page, which contain schedule. Schedul appered from data, which user provided in  **create/** form.

So my problem is, when I filled out the form and redirect to **list/** page, there are no links.
My code:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class File(models.Model):
    file = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    #Further, they are fileds, which is nececary to create schedule. 
    #title = models.CharField('Название Графика', max_length = 50)
    #x_title = models.CharField('Название Оси Х', max_length = 50)
    #y_title = models.CharField('Название Оси Y', max_length = 50)
    #etc...
```

**views.py**:

```
def create(request):

    error = ''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FileForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

            return redirect('grafic:list')
        else:
            error = 'Форма была неверной('

    form = FileForm()

    data = {
        'form': form,
        'error': error,
    }

     return render(request, 'graf/create.html', data)

def list(request):
    qs = File.objects.filter(file=request.user)

    context = {
        'user': request.user,
        'qs': qs,
    }

    return render(request, 'graf/list.html', context)
```

**list.html**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<h2>{% block title %} Profile {% endblock %}</h2>
<p>Username: {{ user }}</p>



{% for b in qs %}
    
    <article class="card">
            <div class="card_wrapper">                  
                <figure class="card_feature">

                    <a href="{% url 'grafic:index' b.id %}"></a>
                    </figure>

                <div class="card_box">
                    <a href="{% url 'grafic:index' b.id %}">
                        <header class="card_item card_header">
                        <h6 class="card__item card__item--small card__label">Твой график</h6>
                        <a class="card__item card__item--small card__title" href="{% url 'grafic:index' b.id %}">
                            {{b.graf_title}}
                        </a>
                        </header>

                        <hr class="card__item card__divider">   
                    </a>
                
                                    
                </div>

            </div>
        </article>      
    
{% endfor %}
```

{% endif %}
{% endblock %}

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path  

from . import views

app_name = 'grafic'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.first, name = 'first'),
    path('create/', views.main, name = 'main'),
    path('list/', views.list, name = 'list'),
    path('files/<int:grafics>', views.index, name = 'index'),
    path('login/', views.loginpage, name = 'loginpage'),
    path('register/', views.registerpage, name = 'registerpage'),
]
```

That's all. Sorry if my code is such inconvenient. Thank you in advance for your cooperation)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMlN2.png)

That is my problem. In the 'file' field there are no user.

Comment: you need to map you views to urls, this is done in urls.py

Comment: Thank you for answerring, but I think in my urls.py everything is correct... I have added **urls.py** code.

Comment: Your File model looks suspicious to me. It allows nulls, so it might be the case that there is no file for specified user, and hence qs=Null, so you will not see file links in this case

Comment: So do I need to delete 'null=True' ?

Comment: I did so and I have error: NOT NULL constraint failed: graf_file.file_id

Comment: no, do not touch your model for a while :) , just add before the for-tag : {% if not qs %} File does not exist {% endif %}. For starters you have to find the reason why file links are not showing up.

Comment: I did that and have "File does not exist"

Comment: So now I am searching reason of why is qs none

Comment: When I entered in admin panel and opened "Files", I had seen that "file" field is empty.

Comment: So, I couldn’t find the reason of my problem. When I add to the “file” field user, other fields like “x_titile” delete. Maybe I should change something in my forms.py ?

Comment: I advise you to ask another question, tell what you want to achieve, describe your current issue, and show all your code. I would imagine, that you are storing files in the File table, however, I can not see it in your current code, you are linking file to User model, on top of that you are naming user_id field 'file'. This looks very misleading.